# array storage and multiplication in verilog

Tags: arrays, verilog

I have a peripheral connected to my altera fpga and am able read data from it using SPI. I would like to store this incoming data into an array, preferably as a floating point value. Further, I have a csv file on my computer and want to store that data in another array, and then after triggering a 'start' signal multiply both arrays and send the output via rs-232 to my pc. Any suggestions on how to go about this? Code for reading data from peripheral is as follows:

```
// we sample on negative edge of clock
always @(negedge SCL) 
begin   
    // data comes as MSB first.
    MOSI_reg[31:0] <= {MOSI_reg[30:0], MOSI}; // left shift for MOSI data

    MISO_reg[31:0] <= {MISO_reg[30:0], MISO}; // left shift for MISO data

end
```

thank you.

Comment: Memory inside an FPGA device is small. How much data do you plan to read from your SPI device? How much data is in your CSV file? Is your data in the CSV file stored as floating point or integer? If your device is going to multiply the first SPI data times the first CSV data, the second SPI data times the second CSV data, and so on, you'd only need one array to store the CSV data. I think this question needs a lot of clarification. The only thing that you provide is a bit shifter, from which the only useful data we gather is that your SPI data is 32 bits wide.

Comment: I plan to read 28 values of 32-bits each. I have double precision floating point values in an array of 1024x28 in my csv. Yes, I intend to multiply the two matrices.

I did some searching in the meantime and found that I can use $readmem to load an array with the values of my csv. Any comments on this? Also, since my SPI data was as fixed point binary, i was planning on converting the data in my csv to fixed point binary, load it into an array and then multiply when in the correct state. Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

A 1024x28 matrix of 32 bits each element requires 917504 bits of RAM in your FPGA, plus another 28*32 = 896 bits for the SPI data. Multiplying these two matrices will result in a vector of 1024x1 elements, thus add 32768 bits for the result. This sums 951168 bits you will need in your device. Does your FPGA chip have this memory?

Asumming you have, yes: you can instantiate a ROM inside your design and initialize with `$readmemh` or `$readmemb` (for values in binary or hexadecimal form respectively).

If precission is not an issue, go for fixed point, as implementing multiplication and addition in floating point is kind of hard job.

You need then a FSM to fill your source vector with SPI data, do the multiplication and store the result in your destination vector. You may consider instantiating a small processor to do the job more easily

Comment: yes, you've understood my issue clearly. I think the data then comes to < 0.1 MB. I have a altera cyclone IV E with 2MB SRAM, 2x64MB SDRAM and 8MB flash. I realize all of them are more than enough to accomplish the task, but just wondering which one is actually used when I instantiate a ROM using $readmem?
At present, precision is not an issue. So yes, I will be going ahead with fixed point. I wanted to use an FPGA implementation as I thought it would be faster than a small processor(NIOS). Speed is critical and this is something I would like to use for image processing.

Comment: Also, as the issue was raised in the comment above, I was wondering if the multiplication for fixed point binary is the same as using a regular multiplier? My numbers are all unsigned, so I felt it should be straightforward. Just wanted your opinion on this.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication is non-trivial in hardware, and 'assign c = a*b' is not necessarily going to produce what you want.

If your FPGA has DSP blocks, you can use one of Altera's customizable IP cores to do your multiplication in a DSP block.  If not, you can still use an IP core to tune the multiplier the way you want (with regards to signed/unsigned, latency, etc.) and likely produce a better result.

Comment: I see, I intend to use only unsigned data values as operands. Also, as mentioned above, I intend multiplication using floating point. I was under the impression that this could be accomplished using a simple multiplier. Just wondering if I would I still need to use an IP core multiplier for this?